# Add different confirm message when checking and unchecking a checkbox in plain js

Tags: javascript, checkbox, addeventlistener

I have two pages where I need to display same behaviour when checking and unchecking a box. On checking, I get the confirm message and upon clicking yes, the box gets checked. For unchecking, I don't want the display message but just uncheck or another option is to display a confirm message but different from the one when checking the checkbox.

Currently I have this:

```
let checkbox_elem = document.querySelectorAll('.first_class, .second_class');
checkbox_elem.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to CHECK this?';
    confirm(message) || e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

There are two class ( first_class and second_class) on two different pages, but irrespective of I check or uncheck, it will always display the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an if condition for the `checked` property:

```js
let checkbox_elem = document.querySelectorAll('.first_class, .second_class');
checkbox_elem.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
  console.log(e.target.checked);
  if(e.target.checked){
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to CHECK this?';
    confirm(message) || e.preventDefault();
  }
  /*else{
    var message = 'Are you sure you want to UNCHECK this?';
    confirm(message) || e.preventDefault();
  }*/
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="first_class" name="scales"
         checked>
  <label for="scales">Scales</label>
```

Based on the true/false value you can show a different message too. Uncomment the else clause to see that.

Comment: Superb. Works flawlessly.

Comment: Sure. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped you